# Why both a key and a secret in many web APIs?

Tags: rest

Many web REST APIs give you a key and a secret. When you make a request to the API, you have to return them **both**. What is the use of this? Would not one of them be enough?

- It is not a public/private key exchange: you give them both, right?
- You're also not hashing your contents with the secret and calculating the other value, as in many hashing algorithms: you always give the same key and secret back.

The only thing I can find is an answer to [How to use a key and secret for verification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992053/how-to-use-a-key-and-secret-for-verification) that says the server can cheaply hash your domain (or probably username or something else) with the secret and check if it matches the key. Is that really the use?

(A bonus would be the name of this mechanism. It doesn't seem to match what I can find on stackoverflow/wikipedia on cryptographic mechanisms.)

---

**Update**: the answer and several of the comments tell me that it *is* a bad idea to pass both a key and the corresponding secret key in a request. It *does* happen in practice, but it is a bad idea nonetheless.

Comment: Please read: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/ That should give you some insight as to why both a key and a secret are used.

Comment: Handy resource! But... I asked about APIs where both secret and key are sent over, so without any HMAC stuff. Like http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/index.html#the-sentry-dsn and also the initial stage when oauthing to github: app id and app secret both in the same request.

Comment: Well, that doesn't look to secure to me. Mind you, I am not a security expert, but the way I understand things, I don't think a secret key should ever be sent with any request. It should be conveyed to you off line (ie in a separate mail or even on paper), and it should be used to hash your request, but never sent anywhere.

Comment: See if my answer to this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482472/when-working-with-most-apis-why-do-they-require-two-types-of-authentication-na/1501112#1501112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be talking about `HMAC Authentication` 
The `key` you are mentioning is something like your account name, it would not be directly used for any authentication. The `secret` would be shared strictly offline and is never send back. In HMAC Authentication you send back a signature derived from a set of paramters agreed between the server and client and of course the `secret` is part of it.

Comment: Well, what I said was that I saw a couple of examples where the secret key *did* get send. For instance on http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/ in step 2 I see a client id *and* a client secret going over the wire.

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees: never take any ol' implementation as the rule. In other words: while that implementation may be sending both key and secret that doesn't mean that this implementation is actualling doing it according to what it should be doing... Mind you, not saying that they aren't doing what they should, just that you shouldn't take (implemented) examples as the norm. Always go back to the source (the spec, the standard, the ...) not someone's interpretation and subsequent implementation of it. Misinterpretations and errors/mistakes do creep in.

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees: For the same reason you should never copy/paste code without understanding what it is doing exactly (and then you could have written it yourself).

Comment: You're right. That's why I'm trying to understand it. And to prevent leaving gaping holes in my implementation in case I decide to write it myself :-)  Thanks for all the info.